# Abbreviations in question-titles, okay?

Tags: discussion, title

Some questions, such as [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32338/what-would-have-happened-if-a-younger-student-had-gotten-his-name-in-the-goblet) (until I edited it), have abbreviations in it that those 'in the know' would know what they refer to (for example, 'st:tng').

A possible concern would be: if this site is to be searchable from the outside (e.g.,  'Google'), or internal search-fields, do such abbreviations 'stunt' some of this site's use as a reference?  The question is, should this be discouraged- or even just a target for edits without calling them out?  Or is this somehow back-end solved with the tag feature  (ie, search-engines see 'star-trek-tng' as 'star trek: the next generation')?

The question I linked-to did not have 'Goblet of Fire' spelled-out anywhere in the question.

There are others I found; but they're easy to find, I felt no need to directly ruffle-feathers.

Comment: Slightly amusing side-note, the example acronym chosen (st:tng) is recognized by Google - it inserts the abbreviated Wikipedia page in the sidebar!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In such cases, please edit the question to have no abbreviation in the title, and all acronyms expanded the first time they're used.

(As you did. Thank you.)

Comment: Aye-aye.  I just wish 'Star Trek: The Next Generation' wasn't such an mouthful.